# How to save variables to a file so that those variables are loaded the next time the site runs?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started programming and now I'm making a simple HTML RPG game. It's pretty much working except I need a way to save. Is there some way to store all the variables in a text file that can be loaded later on? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try localsotrage to store anything

Comment: Using only HTML and JS? Is there a server side component involved at all?

Comment: Yeah only HTML, CSS and JS

Answer (score 2):

You can use [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) or even `cookies`. `local storage` is your best bet, although it doesn't work in older browsers. `cookies` are (more) limited in their capacity (4KB vs 5MB for local storage) and also are sent to the server with each request, which may not be what you want.

Alternatively, you can store the state on your server (you'll need some server side scripting as well), and only store a user/gamer id in a cookie.

Comment: I have no experience in server side scripting, I guess I'll try local storage then, any tips on how to use it?

Comment: @user2514244 You can check if local storage is supported by the browser by using Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/docs/)

Comment: @user2514244 The term `local storage` in my answer is a [link](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to an great explanation of what local storage/html5 storage is and how it works. It also shows some examples and even the use of the `Modernizr` library to detect support of local storage in of the browser.

Answer (score -1):

There is no logic to save it to `.txt` file. You can use [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) or even [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). But `local storage` is better.

Comment: Could you explain local storage please?

Comment: Local storage is one of the areas where native client applications have held an advantage over web applications.